# Delete non-native scheduled tasks from the \ folder in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I would like to delete the 'non-native' scheduled tasks on several machines on my network. The names of these tasks vary (depending on what software the users have installed) but they are all in the root \ folder in the scheduled tasks application.

Using the `schtasks /delete /tn * /f` will delete these tasks, but it also goes into the task subdirectories and deletes all of the native windows tasks which I am sure cannot be a good thing!

I have tried variations of `/tn "\*"` etc.. but schtasks does not accept this input.

There seems to be some powershell code online which may do this, but it appears to only work for windos 8 and above. A lot of my machines are still windows 7.

How can I tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Task Scheduler Scripting Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383607(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
# Create the scripting object
$TaskScheduler = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service

# Connect to the task scheduler library on the local machine
$TaskScheduler.Connect('localhost')

# Retrieve all (non-hidden) tasks from the root folder
$RootFolder = $TaskScheduler.GetFolder('\')
$Tasks = $RootFolder.GetTasks(0)

# Iterate over each task and delete it
foreach($Task in $Tasks){
    $RootFolder.DeleteTask($Task.Name,$null)
}
```